# Get the count from the tables and show the sum of each column

Tags: sql, join

This is below data in Table2

```
ID2        |    Count2
-----------+-----------
1345653         5
534140349       5
682527813       4
687612723       3
704318001       5
```

This is my below data in Table1

```
ID1        |    Count1
-----------+-----------
1345653         4
704318001       4
```

1. If you see the above table this `1345653` in Table2 has `5 count` but in Table1 it has `4 count`, In the same way this ID `704318001` in Table2 has `5 count` but in Table1 it has `4 count`.
2. And also one more thing I need to show, I don't know whether it is possible to do it or not. I want to show the sum of each column also in the end, like sum of Count2 column in the end and sum of Count1 column in the end.

So I need to show like this in the Output. I have my working query for the first part, but I am not sure how to work on second part.

```
ID              Count2   Count1
-----------------------------------
1345653         5        4
534140349       5        0
682527813       4        0
687612723       3        0
704318001       5        4
               22        8
```

Is this possible in sql? If Yes, how can I achieve that?

I have created the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c75b/7) in which only the count thing is working(means first part), And I am not sure how to add the sum of each column feature in that SQL query.

Comment: Which type of database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it work for you?

```
select id2,  SUM(count2),SUM(coalesce(count1, 0)) as count1 
from table2 
 left outer join table1 
  on id1=id2
 group by id2
 with rollup
```

It's mysql syntax, but most RDMS support `ROLLUP` with a small difference in syntax

Comment: Thanks a1ex07, I have one doubt, If I am writing like this `group by id2 order by 1d2 with rollup` then it will work? or is there any problem with that?

Comment: @Nevzz03: You probably already figured it out yourself by that time. `rollup` is a `group by` option, you cannot split clause, `order by` should go after `group by` : `group by ... with rollup order by ...` . Also, as far as I remember, resulset is sorted by expression of `group by`, so there is no need to `order by` the same field.

Answer (score 0):

In standard sql:

```
Select id, Count2,Count1, Count2+Count1 as CountSum
from table2 
left outer join table1 on table1.id=table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a grouping "with rollup". I believe the following query should provide what you desire.  Assuming you're using SQL Server...

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(Table1.ID1, Table2.ID2) AS ID,
    SUM(ISNULL(Table2.Count2, 0)) AS Count2,
    SUM(ISNULL(Table1.Count1, 0)) AS Count1
FROM Table1
FULL JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID2 = Table1.ID1
GROUP BY
    ISNULL(Table1.ID1, Table2.ID2) WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Can you provide me working SQL Fiddle example so that I can see whether it is working or not? That way I can test on my use case.

Comment: Corrected query to return exact results that were requested (copy and pasted into link provided in question for verification). The difference between this query and a1ex07's query is it doesn't matter if just one or both tables match on the ID.  If your looking for a primary driver table their answer might be more correct.